# Get a data from a different table using id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table in my database called `users` and in this table there is a field called `rank`. This field holds the id of the users rank.

I also have a table called 'ranks' in my database, and this table has `id`, `rank_id` and `rank_name`, the `id` being the primary auto increment field, the `rank_id` hold the rank id and this is what is being used in my `users` table.

All is good. I need to display the users `rank_name`, not the `rank_id` when I output what rank they are. Im not a pro at mysql, i am still learning.

How do i get the users `rank`, match it up to the `rank_id` in the table `ranks` and then output the `rank_name` from the corresponding `rank_id`?

Please answer this using `mysql_*.` I know its life is ending soon but this is what im practicing with at the moment, will help me learn how to convert to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: This is a very basic SQL `join` query.  I think you need to learn a bit more about SQL if you are going to be using it.

Comment: So you do have to use join? Ok thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN ranks ON (users.rank_id = ranks.id) WHERE users.id = {userId}`.... that is only an example but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This question has already been answered. If you are not going to help or guide in the right direction someone who is asking for help and is learning, then there is not reason for you to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a query like this

```
 SELECT u.name, r.rank_name
 FROM users AS u
 LEFT JOIN ranks AS r ON u.rank = r.rank_id
```

I would suggest you read about the different joins. Also remember you can join multiple tables in this fashion.

Comment: As you mentioned you should be using PDO/MYSQLI but I see a lot of questions about mysql_ so if you starting editing scripts for people etc you may find it's good to know about mysql_ as that is what they have used, so not necessarily a bad thing you start here, as long as you are aware of the deprecation.

Comment: I am very aware and your reasoning just there is exactly why im starting with mysql. Peoples current scripts will be coded using mysql functions and will not be updated to mysqli or pdo until they do a revamp on their scripts which may not be for a long time. Knowing old and new practices is a good idea i think.